# In AEM Dialog not able to read values from radio button that is inside multifield of dailog

Tags: dialog, aem

Can someone suggest how to read those values from radio button in multifield dialog?

Comment: Please add your dialog config along with the question.

Comment: is this for touch ui or classic? Is your issue: after selecting radio inside a multifield, opening the dialog second time is not displaying the selection? or value selected is not persisted in crx during submit? You can refer to OOTB component /libs/granite/ui/content/userproperties/preferences/form/items/authoring-mode

for a sample radio button.